# Перестал работать Code Runner

Tags: visual-studio-code

Почему-то вдруг перестал работать Code Runner в VS Code: ничего не выводит в output, уже и Node.js обновил, но все равно не работает. Как исправить?
Показывает необработанную ошибку: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uri')
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.